# Server service fails to start, event 7023, error 1079

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, windows-service

**Hello,**

Environment: Windows Server 2008 R2 fully patched, working as Domain Controller in Win 2003 native domain.

Users started to report problems with share, it turned out that server service won't start. I've scrambled google but can't find a thing.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

**Service fails to start, then when starting service I get:**

```
Windows could not start the Server service on SERVERNAME. 
Error 1079: The account specified for this service is different from the account specified for other services running in the same process.
```

**In System Event Log:**

```
Event 7023
The Server service terminated with the following error: The account used is a server trust account. Use your global user account or local user account to access this server.
```

Answer (score 1):

It took a while but here is a solution:

Check your paths in PATH system variable - when it is incorrect Server service won't start (as points to non existing folder etc.)

Use this hotfix or check your paths :)
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2316513

Answer (score 0):

The error messages seem (to me) to be very clear. Either the Server service, or another service in the same process, is running as a named user that shouldn't be. They should all be running as the same account. That account should almost definitely be "local system."

/Edit : Run `tasklist /SVC` and look at how the named services match up (some in groups) to given processes. The "Server" process has a display name of LanManServer, so look for that, it's companion services, and check the "login as" for all of those services

Comment: Thanks mfinni, but this is the core of the problem, service was and is  run under **Local System** 'log on as' user (as it is on all my servers) but still problem occurs :/

Comment: What about the other services that run in the same process?

Comment: Process, as per dependent services, right?
Security Accounts, DCOM - Local System
Server SMB 1 - can't find it, doesn't seems to be service
RPC, RPC endpoint - Network Service

screen here:http://i.imgur.com/VozY1va.png

Comment: Nope, "dependent" doesn't necessarily mean "in the same process." Run 'tasklist /SVC' and look at how the named services match up (some in groups) to given processes. The "Server" process has a display name of LanManServer, so look for that, it's companion services, and check the "login as" for all of those services.

Comment: Mfinni - thanks for tip, I can't be sure for 100% that this is same proces, as LanManServer is not running, but when comparing with working server, it sems that LanManServer should belong to following group, all those services run under 'Local System' account, but Server still can't :/
svchost.exe 840 AeLookupSvc, CertPropSvc, gpsvc, IKEEXT, iphlpsvc, ProfSvc, Schedule, SENS, SessionEnv, ShellHWDetection, Winmgmt,wuauserv

Comment: Run ProcMon and/or ProcExp from Sysinternals (now microsoft) when you try to run it and get a better idea into what's going on. Hint - filter on something to reduce the noise. On my Vista machine, it looks like a Command Line contains "netsvcs" would do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is in the first referenced error message.

More specifically, unless all users are logged in as SERVERNAME it will not work. (or if all users are logged into the account that originated the process)

The rest of this is merely speculation but I imagine the process originated from an account named 'local system' thus SERVERNAME and local system are the two accounts trying to run services in the same process.